# How to add legend in a highlighted graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure, legend

I want to add legend in a graph G according to different highlighted edges. Is it possible to do it with only one graph `G`?

Here is a toy example to play with. I have a plot `G`.

```
adj =[0 0 1 1 1;   % adjacency matrix
      1 0 1 0 1;
      0 1 0 1 1;
      1 1 1 0 1;
      0 0 1 0 0]
G = digraph(adj);
```

I highlighted all edges with 3 colors according to types of edges. 3 types of edges indicate there are 3 different relation between nodes in my case.

This is how I highlighted all edges:

```
M(:,:,1)=[0 0 1 0 0;1 0 0 0 1;0 0 0 0 0;1 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 0 0];
M(:,:,2)=[0 0 0 1 0; 0 0 1 0 0;0 1 0 0 1;0 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 0];              
M(:,:,3)=[0 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1 0;0 1 1 0 1;0 0 0 0 0];
```

The difficulty in my problem is that I have to remove vertices whose out-degree is less than some integel (say it's 2). Thus I can't plot 3 graphs independently.

```
rmvNode=find(outdegree(G)<2);    % outdegree is the reason why single G is neccesary
adj(rmvNode,:)=[]; adj(:,rmvNode)=[];
M(:,rmvNode,:)=[]; M(rmvNode,:,:)=[];
G=digraph(adj);
```

Then we can plot it.

```
for k=1:3           %Looping depending on the third dimension
    [r,c]= find(M(:,:,k));  %Finding non-zero elements
    s{k}=r;     t{k}=c;    
end
h=plot(G);
highlight(h,s{1},t{1},'EdgeColor','r');
highlight(h,s{2},t{2},'EdgeColor','g');
highlight(h,s{3},t{3},'EdgeColor','b');
```

[image]
My ideal situation would be a legend like this: assign red edges to label 'type 1', assign blue edges to 'type 2', and assign green ones to 'type 3'. I want something like this:

[image]

Once more: I can't plot 3 graphs independently according to 3 pages in M, combine 3 plots together and then add a legend. Because as you can see, `outdegree` requires a whole graph `G` as input, it's not viable to divide `G` into `G1`, `G2` and `G3`.

Comment: You can use [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) for that purpose.

Comment: btw from these lines of your code, `highlight(h,s{2},t{2},'EdgeColor','g');`
`highlight(h,s{3},t{3},'EdgeColor','b');`it seems  that you'd want green color for type 2 and blue color for type 3 (I followed this in my answer) but in the rough figure, you exchanged these colors.

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks for pointing it out and the idea of invisible plot. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to manipulate the [**`legend`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) function by adding an invisible [**`plot`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) like this:

```
%put this at the end of your code
hold on;                                      %to retain current plot
ax=plot(NaN,NaN,'r',NaN,NaN,'g',NaN,NaN,'b'); %plotting invisible points of desired colors
legend(ax,'Type 1','Type 2','Type 3');        %adding the legend
```

which gives:

[image: output]

Comment: It's better to use `nan`s as your dummy data, as those a truly invisible.